# Next js localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I want to redirect user to login page if there is not token in cookies and user requests any page:

```js
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { AuthProvider } from "./_providers/AppProvider";
import AppLayout from "./AppLayout";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { redirect, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { headers } from "next/headers";

import Router from "next/router";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Loyalty",
  description: "Loyalty app",
};

//TODO: check token on every page load
// get user session from database, if token exists in sessions table, proceed, else redirect to login

export default async function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();

  const token = cookieStore.get("token")?.value;

  const headersList = headers();
  const domain = headersList.get("host") || "";

  if (!token && domain !== "localhost:3000/login") {
    return redirect("http://localhost:3000/login");
  }

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <AppLayout>{children}</AppLayout>
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

It gives me:

localhost redirected you too many times.

Why it redirects me over and over?

Comment: probably the value of domain is not 'localhost:3000/login', you probably want to look at the request url instead of of headers.get('host'), but im no expert in react or next.js

Comment: it's the same, I checked, but it redirects over and over, how I can prevent it and run this if check only once ?

Comment: you sure it contains the path /login, because typically the host part is domain and port only, try console.log the domain value before if(!token && domain !==, because the redirect is probably coming from there, also check that headersList.get('host') returns a string because you use strict equality

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that the host header will not include the `/login` and will redirect you to the same page all the time